# Web.xml is generated in a different directory

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, web, web.xml

I have imported a project from Git. The web.xml file is in `WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml` and working well in the other PC.

When I run the app on my current server, the app starts without reading the web.xml file. So, I tried to invistigte this and found out that there is another web.xml file generated in `src/main/webapps/WEB-INF/web.xml`. Why is that?

I want to use the web.xml in the directory `WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml`, how do I do that?

Comment: `src/main/webapps/` is maven/gradle's default folder for web contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In file .settings/org.eclipse.wst.common.component, I changed the line describing the location of default root source.

to be

```
 <wb-resource deploy-path="/" source-path="/WebContent" tag="defaultRootSource"/>
```

This problem occurred because I have used import Java project instead of Import Maven project.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your project is packaged with maven (maven was tagged), so you can configure the war plugin and specify a custom path for your web.xml

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <webXml>/path/to/webXml</webXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```